# Can i really read LOB through closed connection?

Tags: java, oracle, inputstream, connection-pooling, wildfly

I use wildfly-8.2.0.Final. There is connection pool (Oracle) on this server.
Look at following code:

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> fetchSome(String query)
        throws OracleQueryProcessorException {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    try {
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) initCtx.lookup(driver);
        try (Connection con = ds.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                rs.next();
                HashMap<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                String name = rsmd.getColumnName(1);
                Object value = rs.getObject(1);
                if (value instanceof Blob) {
                    Blob bl = (Blob) value;
                    if (bl.length() > 0)
                        value = bl.getBinaryStream();
                    else
                        value = null;
                }
                row.put(name, value);
                result.add(row);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new OracleQueryProcessorException();
        }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new OracleQueryProcessorException();
    }
    return result;
}
```

And this is usage of this function:

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) fetchSome("SELECT BLOB_FIELD FROM TEST WHERE ID = 1").get(0).get("BLOB_FIELD");
            if (is != null) {
                byte[] a = new byte[3];
                is.read(a);
            }
```

Reading from this stream is working!! How can it work? Connection is closed (cause using try-with-resources clause). Reading from this stream take no connection from pool (All pool's connections are available).

Answer (score 0):

`fetchSome()` opens a `Connection`, sends the query, and then reads the data back into the resulting ArrayList. Then `fetchSome` closes the `Connection` and returns the `ArrayList`. The code you are curious about then reads from the `ArrayList` that was returned, not from the `Connection` that was, as you correctly noticed, closed.

By the time your method returns, all database communication has finished, and all the data has been copied into the returned list, from which it can then be read as often and as late as you want, without needing a `Connection` again.

Comment: when i do bl.getBinaryStream(), i'm not reading data from blob, i just getting InputStream object.

Comment: LOB content has not already readed from DB when connection is closed

Answer (score 0):

Does it really work for various BLOB sizes? Good thresholds are:

- 4000B (limit where BLOB might be in lined in the row - not stored aside)
- 2000B (maximum size for RAW) - BLOB can be casted to RAW somewhere
- 16KB, 32KB
- some huge value bigger than JVM heap size

AFAIK on OCI level(C client library) LOBs might be "pre-allocated" .i.e. some smaller portion of BLOB can be sent to client, although it was not requested yet by the client. This should reduce number of round-trips between database and client.

Also you should try check v$instance view to check whether the connection really was closed. Cooperation between JDBC and Oracle is tricky sometimes.

For example temporary LOBs created via Connection.createBLOB() are treaded differently than any other temporary lobs by the database. I think it is because Oracle database can not talk to JVM GC and it does not know when really the java instance was disposed. So these lobs are kept in the database "forever".

Comment: i had read 250MB LOB and i didn't see any influence on JVM used memory.

Comment: i try DROP TABLE while reading. reading is stopped :) I think i means that reading really take data from blob not from jvm memory.

Comment: this is also strange. Oracle should not allow you to drop the table, if some cursor it touching it. What is the exact type of `Connection con`. Maybe it is some PooledConnection (not OracleConnection) and calling close on it, will just make it returned into connection pool. This is really a corner case, the behavior might differ with each JDBC dirver version

Comment: What ORA-XXX error you get when the table is dropped?